# How to add text around dynamically assigned aria labels with Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, accessibility

I am very new to `vue.js` and accessibility,

I am trying to make an element be announced by the screen reader as ("This is " + person.name).

I was able to announce the person.name with `:aria-label="person.name"` but I am not able to add text around this.

How do I add text around the dynamically assigned `:aria-label`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with  `:aria-label="'This is ' + person.name"`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      person: { name: "Logan" }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs.btn)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
<button ref="btn" :aria-label="'This is ' + person.name">name</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Logan Gauchat you are welcome, cheers :)